# Charts.js - need to update centered value when click (default: delete) segment

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to update centered value of my doughnut chart.js when i delete a segment. Below my situation:

[image: Before delete element]

[image: After delete legend-label]

So the number 46 doesn't change. It is got by the sum of the numbers that of dataset. So i think: when i delete a legend-label, my dataset won't be updated but only the design of my graphic. I want to change that centered number.
This code is how i set a centered value:

```
         Chart.pluginService.register({
        beforeDraw: function (chart) {
            var me = this;
            var opts = me.options;
            if (chart.config.options.title) {
                var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                ctx.align = 'left';
            }
            /* function removeData(chart) {
                 console.log('ciao')
                 chart.data.labels.pop();
                 chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
                     dataset.data.pop();
                 });
                 chart.update();
             }
             var segments = chart.segments;
             for (var index = 0; index < segments.length; index++) {
                 if (activeLabel == segments[index].label) {
                     myChart.removeData(index);
                 }
             }*/

            if (chart.config.options.elements.center) {
                //Get ctx from string
                var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
                //Get options from the center object in options
                var centerConfig = chart.config.options.elements.center;
                var fontStyle = centerConfig.fontStyle || 'Arial';
                var txt = centerConfig.text;
                var color = centerConfig.color || '#000';
                var sidePadding = centerConfig.sidePadding || 20;
                var sidePaddingCalculated = (sidePadding / 100) * (chart.innerRadius * 2)
                //Start with a base font of 30px
                ctx.font = "45px " + fontStyle;

                //Get the width of the string and also the width of the element minus 10 to give it 5px side padding
                var stringWidth = ctx.measureText(txt).width;
                var elementWidth = (chart.innerRadius * 2) - sidePaddingCalculated;

                // Find out how much the font can grow in width.
                var widthRatio = elementWidth / stringWidth;
                var newFontSize = Math.floor(30 * widthRatio);
                var elementHeight = (chart.innerRadius * 2);

                // Pick a new font size so it will not be larger than the height of label.
                //var fontSizeToUse = Math.min(newFontSize, elementHeight);
                var fontSizeToUse = centerConfig.fontSizeToUse;
                //Set font settings to draw it correctly.
                ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
                var centerX = ((chart.chartArea.left + chart.chartArea.right) / 2);
                var centerY = ((chart.chartArea.top + chart.chartArea.bottom) / 2);
                ctx.font = fontSizeToUse + "px " + fontStyle;
                ctx.fillStyle = color;

                //Draw text in center
                ctx.fillText(txt, centerX, centerY);
            }
        },
        afterUpdate: function (update) {

            update.config.options.elements.center.text = bloccoUno[0];
            console.log('afterUpdate: ' + update.config.options.elements.center.text);
        },
        afterLayout: function (update) {
            console.log('afterLayout: ' + update);
        },
        afterDatasetsUpdate: function (update) {
            console.log('afterDatasetsUpdate: ' + update);
        },
        afterDatasetUpdate: function (update) {
            console.log('afterDatasetUpdate: ' + update);
        }

    });
```

And this is how i define WHICH number need to be centered:

```
      self.blocks[0].elenco[1].doughnutChartOptions['elements'] =
        {
            center: {
                text: self.blocks[0].elenco[1].numero,
                fontSizeToUse: 40,
                color: '#26313E', //Default black
                fontStyle: 'Helvetica', //Default Arial
                sidePadding: 15 //Default 20 (as a percentage)
            }
        };
```

doughnutChartOptions are just my chart.js options. 
So...how i can change that number (sum of my data in dataset/legend values) on deleting (this is a default function of chart.js) an element from the legend? 
I tried without results to intercept this deleting, but doesn't work.

Sorry for my english and thanks to all :)

Comment: you need to call this function ctx.fillText(txt, centerX, centerY);  txt change this one with updated text

Comment: Text is not dynamically updated...i need to get text updatet after deleting and i can't find it anywhere...

Comment: Provide url or full html page to resolve this